# wxPython dialogs: How to validate inputs in multiple controls?

Tags: validation, dialog, wxpython

I have a `wx.Dialog` with several input fields. When the OK button is pressed I want to run validations such as:

- If one of three fields is filled in, all three must be filled in.
- If a radiobutton is set, then it's corresponding field must not be empty.

I know about the normal [validators](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/validator_overview.html) that get attached to a control with `wx.Window.SetValidator()`. But these just validate the content of their respective control.

I tried attaching a validator to the `wx.Dialog`, but this is not called unfortunately.

I tried binding the event from the `ID_OK` button to a handler to do the validation there, but the result is that the dialog doesn't close anymore.

What is the proper way to do this kind of validation?

Below is my code with what I tried:

```python
import wx


class DialogValidator(wx.Validator):
    def Clone(self):
        return DialogValidator()

    def Validate(self, win):
        print("this method is never called :-(")
        field1 = win.field1.GetValue()
        field2 = win.field2.GetValue()
        field3 = win.field3.GetValue()
        if len(field1) > 0 or len(field2) > 0 or len(field3) > 0:
            # if one of these is filled in, all three must
            if len(field1) == 0 or len(field2) == 0 or len(field3) == 0:
                wx.MessageBox("All three fields must be filled in!", "Error")
                return False
        return True

    def TransferToWindow(self):
        return True

    def TransferFromWindow(self):
        return True


class MyDialog(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.field1 = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, "")
        self.field2 = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, "")
        self.field3 = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, "")
        self.radio1 = wx.RadioButton(self, wx.ID_ANY, "radio1", style=wx.RB_GROUP)
        self.radio2 = wx.RadioButton(self, wx.ID_ANY, "radio2")
        self.dialog_btn_sizer = wx.StdDialogButtonSizer()
        self.dialog_btn_sizer.AddButton(wx.Button(self, wx.ID_OK))
        self.dialog_btn_sizer.AddButton(wx.Button(self, wx.ID_CANCEL))
        self.dialog_btn_sizer.Realize()

        main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        main_sizer.Add(self.radio1)
        main_sizer.Add(self.radio2)
        main_sizer.Add(self.field1)
        main_sizer.Add(self.field2)
        main_sizer.Add(self.field3)
        main_sizer.Add(self.dialog_btn_sizer, 0, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        self.SetSizer(main_sizer)
        main_sizer.Fit(self)
        self.Layout()

        self.SetValidator(DialogValidator())  # doesn't work unfortunately

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_ok, id=wx.ID_OK)  # doesn't work either

    def on_ok(self, event):
        field1 = self.field1.GetValue()
        field2 = self.field2.GetValue()
        field3 = self.field3.GetValue()
        if len(field1) > 0 or len(field2) > 0 or len(field3) > 0:
            # if one of these is filled in, all three must
            if len(field1) == 0 or len(field2) == 0 or len(field3) == 0:
                wx.MessageBox("All three fields must be filled in!", "Error")
                event.Skip()
                return
        # Note that I do NOT call event.Skip() here!
        # I was hoping the original handler would pick up the event
        #   and properly close the dialog -> unfortunately this is not the case
        print("inputs fine, now the dialog should get closed")
```

Answer (score 2):

I now solved it by setting a validator on one field that accesses the other fields by going over the dialog. I found out that *win* in `wx.Validator.Validate(self, win)` refers to the underlying `wx.Dialog`.

(Why handling the *ID_OK* button didn't work I don't know, but this would be another question.)

I'm posting my solution in the hope it helps others struggling with validators:

```py
import wx


class FieldValidator(wx.Validator):
    def Clone(self):
        return FieldValidator()

    def Validate(self, win):
        # 'win' refers to the dialog,
        # so I can access the other controls like this:
        field1 = win.field1.GetValue()
        field2 = win.field2.GetValue()
        field3 = win.field3.GetValue()
        # btw: with self.GetWindow() I can get the control being validated
        if len(field1) > 0 or len(field2) > 0 or len(field3) > 0:
            # if one of these is filled in, all three must
            if len(field1) == 0 or len(field2) == 0 or len(field3) == 0:
                wx.MessageBox("All three fields must be filled in!", "Error")
                return False
        return True

    def TransferToWindow(self):
        return True

    def TransferFromWindow(self):
        return True


class MyDialog(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.field1 = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, "")
        self.field2 = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, "")
        self.field3 = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, "")
        self.radio1 = wx.RadioButton(self, wx.ID_ANY, "radio1", style=wx.RB_GROUP)
        self.radio2 = wx.RadioButton(self, wx.ID_ANY, "radio2")
        self.dialog_btn_sizer = wx.StdDialogButtonSizer()
        self.dialog_btn_sizer.AddButton(wx.Button(self, wx.ID_OK))
        self.dialog_btn_sizer.AddButton(wx.Button(self, wx.ID_CANCEL))
        self.dialog_btn_sizer.Realize()

        main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        main_sizer.Add(self.radio1)
        main_sizer.Add(self.radio2)
        main_sizer.Add(self.field1)
        main_sizer.Add(self.field2)
        main_sizer.Add(self.field3)
        main_sizer.Add(self.dialog_btn_sizer, 0, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        self.SetSizer(main_sizer)
        main_sizer.Fit(self)
        self.Layout()

        self.field1.SetValidator(FieldValidator())
```